# jQuery Incremental Percentage Change in .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following code works:

```
  $('.container').css({
    'left': '-100%' 
  });
```

This code doesn't:

```
  $('.container').css({
    'left': '-=100%' 
  });
```

It's instead changed to pixels. I've tried adding the `%` on the end as a string but it still doesn't work. I can't figure out how to get it to stay as a percentage whilst incrementing/decrementing.

Is it possible?

Comment: Using CSS, this is not possible. using normal javascript, you have to calculate the vaues then assign it inside css property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/tNYVJ/

Its working here.. 
    Please look at this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $("div").animate({left:'-=10%'}, 5000, 'linear');
 });
});
```

Comment: Animate does work, but I'd hoped to use css transitions because their a little smoother, if I can't work it out I'll accept this answer and find a jquery easing plugin or something.

Comment: When a css transition is applied to the element, it acts weird, first slide is fine but after that it flies along to the fourth slide. Works fine with css transition removed though.

Comment: Oh.. did u implemented using css transition?? IF s? could u show me the output??

Comment: I may have figured out a solution. If I use velocity.js, I get better performance than animate, as well as the same bezier easing I used in the transition :)

Comment: Sorted, changed to Velocity instead of animate. Thank you! :)

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html.. Easing types..
Cool Ya :):)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `animate()` [Animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to increment the percentage

```
$('#yourId').animate({
            left: previousLeftValue+IncrementValue //Assuming that previous left value is stored somewhere
        }, 300 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the following method!

**Jquery**

```
var x = $('#element');
x.css('left', (parseFloat(x.css('left')) + 10) + '%');
```

**CSS**

```
#element{
  left : 5%;
  position : relative; //Its important
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sYBq/). Hope  this helps.